# How do I fix a sagging headliner

Tags: cosmetic, interior

My headliner has started to sag right over the front passenger. While it is not causing me any issues (it is not so low that it hits the passenger or distracts me) it is very ugly. What is the best way to go about fixing it?

Comment: thumbtacks! :-)

Comment: This one hits home for me.  I remember this issue in one of my first cars.

Comment: @Troggy, I think this is a a common first car experience for a good portion of people. First car check list is **1)** Runs **2)** Has seat belts **3)** headliner sags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend an adhesive that is designed for headliners (ala [Permatex](http://www.autozone.com/autozone/accessories/Permatex-16-3-4-oz-aerosol-can-heavy-duty-headliner-and-carpet-adhesive/_/N-259v;jsessionid=A01F3385DC6D55E4885B3AD24F5CD22A.diyprod2-b2c4?counter=0&itemIdentifier=130215_0_0_)).

An alternative to this would be contact cement, although you might have some bleedthrough.

If the headliner has stretched with age you might need to buy a new headliner.

Comment: Or perhaps you could glue from the center out and trim the headliner at the edges.

Answer (score 3):

Had this problem once too in an older truck. There are a few options:

1. Re-upholster it. You could do this yourself, or have it professionally done. If you were to do it, you would need to remove the trim pieces in the inside along the roof, and then remove the fabric. It may be attached to the sheet metal with some plastic clips. You will want to save as many of these as you can. Then, make a decision as to whether you want to completely remove the old fabric, cover over it, or just tighten it. Then put the new fabric on, using some adhesive in the middle, and use some staples to stale the back side of the fabric near the ends, that would be covered up by the trim. Re-install, and you should be good to go!
2. Tack it up. You could easily do this yourself, just use some small metal screws that match the color of the fabric.

Answer (score 2):

Curtain tension rods, the ones that go on the inside of the window frame. I got a "thicker" one ($4+ walmart) for between the front and back seats and a "thinner" one ($2+ walmart) for between the clothes holders in the back. I needed more clearance and pool noodles were out of season, so I used plumbing insulation noodles (12 ft for $2+ walmart). I don't claim to be an expert, but it was a quick and cheap fix for my '98 Buick.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to not spend too much time on trying to reattach it with spray-on adhesives. I once removed a headliner and then scraped all the loose foam off. Then sprayed and glued it back on. It lasted a few months, if that long. I got another car re-upholstered professionally and it cost less that I thought it would and it was beautiful.

Comment: May I ask how much it cost?